# Find name of currently running SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I swear I've done this before but I can't find the code or an answer.  I want to get the name of a currently running SparkContext and read it into a variable or print it to the screen.  Something along the lines of:

```
val myContext = SparkContext.getName
```

So for example, if I was in spark-shell and ran it it would return "sc".  Anyone know how to get that?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not quite sure I follow... by name, do you mean the name of the application? If so, you would call `appName`. In spark-shell, for example: `sc.appName`.

If you're asking to get the name of the variable holding the context, then I'm not sure you can. `sc` is just the val used to access the context inside spark-shell, but you could name it anything you want in your own application.

[EDIT]
There's a `getOrCreate` method on the SparkContext which can return an existing created and registered context. Will this do what you want?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#getOrCreate()

Comment: If I created val sc = new SparkContext() I would later want to be able to say something like val CtxName = SparkContext.name and return "sc" or something I could cast as a string with value "sc".  The reason I am trying to do this is I am trying to use a 3rd party library that creates (supposedly) the SparkContext for me, but it doesn't seem to be there and if it is, it's called soemthing other than "sc".  I was hoping to just get the name to verify it's exsitence and then be able to create new SQLContext with it, rather than digging through their code to figure it out.

Comment: Umm, I don't think an instance knows the name of the val it's stored in. What you're essentially asking for is the SparkContext to know where instances of it are stored, which seems a bit mad. If you're using a library that creates a context for you, just look at their code to see what it's called (if you're inheriting a trait or another class, it shouldn't be too difficult).

Comment: I've just updated my answer with something that may help you - the `getOrCreate` static method in `SparkContext` will return a previously created and registered context, or give you a new one. I don't think you can run more than one instance of the context in parallel, so if there is one, you should get it.